# Lightning PageReference Object Passing Field Values in standard__object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, workspaceapi

I am launching a [Subtab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_openSubtab.htm) using the [Lightning Workspace API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI), and using an [Aura pageReference object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) to specify that I want to create a new Task.

I want to pre-populate the `WhatId` on the Task when the new `standard__object` tab opens.

I set the `WhatId` in the `state` I want to pass into the `pageReference` object:

```
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
var recordId = component.get("v.recordId") // confirmed this is my intended WhatId recordId
workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(enclosingTabId) {
    workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
            parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
            pageReference: 
            {    
                "type": "standard__objectPage",
                "attributes": {
                    "objectApiName": "Task",
                    "actionName": "new"
                },
                "state": {
                    "WhatId": recordId
                }
            }
        }).then(function(subtabId) {
            console.log("The new subtab ID is:" + subtabId);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("error");
        });
    })
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

But it doesn't appear to be passing the input as a query parameter - and when the *new record* lightning component opens in the subtab the `Related:` input field is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the appropriate answer is to use the [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) event:

```
var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Task",
    "defaultFieldValues": {
         // "WhatId": 
    }
});
createRecordEvent.fire();
```

Also, it appears that when fired *from within* a subtab this event will open a new subtab, I am not sure if it works the other way around.